# Multiclass classification, show raw predictions better in Scala with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

Working with the Iris dataset (LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS(), multiclass classification).
I pulled my data into an rdd, converted to a Dataframe, done some tidying up on it. Created a labelindex on the Iris plant class/label field. Created a feature vector of the other fields.
Took these two fields of a dataframe and converted into a labelpoint rdd instance, where I can feed the data into LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS().

Here is some predictor code:

```
val model = new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS()
  .setNumClasses(10)
  .setIntercept(true)
  .setValidateData(true)
  .run(training)
```

Scores and labels:

```
val scoreAndLabels_ofTrain = training.map {
  point =>
    val score = model.predict(point.features)
    (score, point.label)
}
```

I wanted to see the predictions

```
scoreAndLabels_ofTrain.take(200).foreach(println)
```

The only problem is, I got this example from a book, pretty much.
I was kind hoping to see a dataset, that shows the feature columns, what the predicted number was, what probability score it gave,  etc
I'd imagine I'd need to do a conversion of the labelindex, if i wanted to see the string data they represent.

How do I get better looking, tabular data as close as possible to the original dataset, with predictions against them?
I think i'm missing a trick here somewhere.

The output to above looks like:

```
(2.0,2.0)
(2.0,2.0)
(2.0,2.0)
(2.0,2.0)
(2.0,2.0)
...
```

What does this even mean? Not sure how to read/interpret the data
For the first line,is it saying, it predicted "2.0", and the actual label was "2.0"?
Am I understanding it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you have is the (Label,Prediction) in form of a **RDD[(Double, Double)]** when you apply the map to the input dataset and make the prediction for each element. But, you are using the mlib LR implementation. You can use directly the Dataframe implementation. Take a look to the [example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#logistic-regression). The fit function optimizes the model and return a [LogisticRagressionModel](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/LogisticRegressionModel.html). Apply the transform method to your input Dataframe and a new column with the prediction will be added.

Comment: The "mlib LR implementation" is that the old way? Just so I have my definitions right in my head, and the "apache-spark-ml" implementation is the better and more recent way we should be doing? And that link you posted, leads to that?

Comment: You should use ML whenever you can. Working with RDDs directly in Spark is useful in advanced tasks, but for normal ML use Dataframe implementation.

Comment: // Fit the model
val lrModel = lr.fit(training)

Once I fit the training data to lr model, per the example link your sent for multiclass logistic regression. How do I output a dataframe, with the new prediction column, raw prediction, probilities sitting alongside per record? thanks

Comment: use the setPredictionCol function. Once you apply the transform function to you dataframe you will get the new column in the resulting dataframe. There is an "evaluate" method that you can use too to extract a summary over a test dataframe.

Comment: ok, Thanks Emi! Got it working now! You're a legend!